# Count the number of occurrences of a char in each sequence in a fasta file with multiple sequences using bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep, fasta

I want to count the number of occurrences of a char in each sequence in a fasta file with multiple sequences, but with the method I use I count the total of the char in the fasta file:

```
grep -o 'G' my_sequence.fasta | wc -l
```

Is there some way to do it with each of the sequences using the fasta file with multiple sequences?

the fasta file look as below

```
>sequence1
CCGTGGGTCAATCCCGTA
>sequence2
CCGTGGGGCACTCCCGTA
>sequence3
TTGTGGGTCAATCCCGTC
>sequence4
CCCGGGTGCACTCCCGTA
```

Comment: What do you want to count exactly? Count number of Cs, number of Gs, number of As, number of Ts? Or count Gs for sequence1, Gs for sequence2, etc.? How big is your file? Please provide the expected output for your given fasta file.

Comment: `awk` might be an option:  `awk '{ if($0 !~ "^>") print $0 " " gsub(/G/, "")}' your.fasta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `awk` that counts the number of `G` in each sequence; it discards the possible header in the FASTA file and supports multi-line sequences. Also, the description lines in the FASTA file might contain more than just the sequence ID, for example `>MCHU ‑ Calmodulin …`. The code only outputs the ID, i.e. `>MCHU`.

```bash
awk -v char=G '
    /^>/ {
        if (label != "") {
            print label, gsub(char, "", sequence)
            sequence = ""
        }
        label = $1
        next 
    }
    { sequence = sequence $0 }
    END {
        if (label != "")
            print label, gsub(char, "", sequence)
    }
' file.fasta
```

```
>sequence1 5
>sequence2 6
>sequence3 5
>sequence4 5
```

**remark:** Be aware that the `char` parameter in argument of the `awk` command is a **regex** and that C‑style escape sequences in it will be **unescaped**; well, it doesn't really matter for your use‑case (i.e. for characters that don't have any special meaning in regex nor C‑escaping).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk -F'^>' '(NF +=__= OFS = "")*(RS==ORS) ? ORS = " :: " \
>                                   \
> : $(+(ORS = RS))=sprintf((_=" %s\47s = %4u |")(_)(_)_,
>                           _="C", gsub(_,__), _="G", gsub(_,__),
>                           _="A", gsub(_,__), _="T", length($+_))'
> ```

```
sequence1 ::  C's =    6 | G's =    5 | A's =    3 | T's =    4 |
sequence2 ::  C's =    7 | G's =    6 | A's =    2 | T's =    3 |
sequence3 ::  C's =    5 | G's =    5 | A's =    2 | T's =    6 |
sequence4 ::  C's =    8 | G's =    5 | A's =    2 | T's =    3 |
```